# compare matrix matlab

Tags: math, matlab, matrix

in following code I'm disappointed because I want to let matlab do what I able to do per hand.
This code is actually working well, if I write it by hand for every step, which is of course absoulte silly:) But could anybody point out the mistake if I try to do it with loops as you see in commented part:( Thanks again,
mgm

aim of code: ask matlab whether x(1)

```
    clear;
x=[0 2 4 6 8 10];
y=[0 1.1 1.3 2 2.1 3.6 4.5 8.3 9];
z=zeros(9);
for j=1:length(y)
%     for i=1:length(x)
%         for k=1:length(y)
%         if (x(i)<y(j))&&(y(j)<x(i+1))
%             z(j,k)=(x(1)+x(2))./2;
%         else 
%             z(j,k)=y(j);
%             
%         end
%         end
%    end
% end
       if (x(1)<y(j))&&(y(j)<x(1+1))
            z(j,1)=(x(1)+x(2))./2;
        else 
            z(j,1)=y(j);

        end
        if (x(2)<y(j))&&(y(j)<x(2+1))
            z(j,2)=(x(2)+x(3))./2;
        else 
            z(j,2)=y(j);
        end
        if (x(3)<y(j))&&(y(j)<x(3+1))
            z(j,3)=(x(3)+x(4))./2;
        else 
            z(j,3)=y(j);
        end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop, you write `z(j,k)` but in the code without loop, it looks like you are doing `z(j,i)`

also in the loopwyou write: `(x(1)+x(2))`, without loop, it looks like `(x(i)+x(1+i))`

You should write:

```
for j=1:length(y)
    for i=1:length(x)
        if (x(i)<y(j))&&(y(j)<x(i+1))
            z(j,i)=(x(i)+x(i+1))./2;
         else 
            z(j,i)=y(j);
        end
    end
end
```